# python simplekml change shape of newpoint

Tags: python, simplekml

I am trying to change the default Yellow Push-PIN place marker to rectangle or pixel.
after running code below I still getting default Yellow Push-PIN place marker.

```
import simplekml
#from simplekml import Shape,Color
kml = simplekml.Kml()
pt2=kml.newpoint(name="test", coords=[(18.432314,-33.988862)])
#both code below are not working.
pt2.style.iconstyle.icon.shape='rectangle'
pt2.style.iconstyle.shape='rectangle'
pt2.style.iconstyle.color='ffffff00'
kml.save("test.kml")
```

Answer (score 1):

To change the shape of the icon, change the href property of the iconstyle which is the URL of the icon. Can see a list of icons for use in Google Earth displayed [here](http://kml4earth.appspot.com/icons.html).

In posted code above, "shape" is not a property of icon nor is it a part of iconstyle. The structure of the icon and iconstyle property is defined by the [KML spec](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#iconstyle).

Updated code to output KML with a custom icon style:

```python
import simplekml

kml = simplekml.Kml()
pt2 = kml.newpoint(name="test", coords=[(18.432314,-33.988862)])
# use square icon
pt2.style.iconstyle.icon.href = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/placemark_square.png'
# set color of icon to be cyan (RGB=#00ffff)
pt2.style.iconstyle.color ='ffffff00' # aabbggrr
print("Output: test.kml")
kml.save("test.kml")
```